# Can not run app in Android studio on real device. java.io.IOException

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm beginner in Android development. Sorry if my question is silly.

The problem is every time i run app in android studio on real device - i got following error

```
10/03 12:09:22: Launching app
```

> ```
> $ adb push C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\P004_BasicViews\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/ru.starandroid.p004_basicviews
> java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> ```
>
> Error while Installing APK

I tried finding solutions on the Internet. All they recommended - I did, but it didn't work:

ADB does see the device. ("adb devices" - shows it)
USB debugging is activated on device.
I tried to change from MTP to PTP protocol.

I use the latest Android studio 2.2.
Windows 7 x64, no antiVirus software is installed.
Device - Samsung s5, android version 6.0.1

Comment: try changing your device cable... might be the issue in device cable..

Comment: changing cable,changing port,updating adb and using following commands might help: `adb kill-server` `adb start-server` . If none of that works change device :)

Comment: Cable is fine. I tried another one - same result. (and windows wouldn't see the device if cable were broken).
I tried this commandos - didn't work. I tried another device - got same error.
Tried different USB ports. ADB is updated.

Comment: Did you grant permission on the device for the PC?

Comment: Also, check phone charge jack. data line may be interrupted while charging lines are working.